# My while loop with char doesnt work. Some help please

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

So i have this peace of code:

```
int choice_dig;
char choice_dup;
printf("Welcome to the mystery number game.\n");
printf("How many digits do you want to use (3 to 5)?");
scanf("%d", &choice_dig);
while (choice_dig<3 || choice_dig>5)
{
    printf("\nPlease choose a number between 3 and 5.\t");
    scanf("%d",&choice_dig);
}
printf("\nDo you want to allow duplicate digits (y or n)?");
scanf(" %c", &choice_dup);
while (choice_dup != 'y' || choice_dup != 'n')
{
    printf("\nInvalid entry. Please choose y for yes and n for no.\t");
    choice_dup = getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

The choice_dup is already assinged as a char var at the start of the main. So when i run this its all good. But even when i press y or n it cant recognize it and the loop never ends. No matter what i type. Can someone help me and expain to me what wrong?

Comment: One of the conditions is always true -> their disjunction will always be true.

Comment: `choice_dup` will always be either not `y` or not `n`

Comment: The problem is in your condition. You need to check using AND instead of OR. When you hit 'Y' it is different to 'N'. You want to validate when it's different to 'Y' AND different to 'N'

Comment: The root cause is an inability to debug.  If you had broken up the complex conditional into two expressions with intermediate booean vars for use in the while, you would surely have spotted the logical error, either with a debugger or with printf logging.  You should stop writing code now and learn some debugging.

Comment: after this line: scanf(" %c", &choice_dup); the code needs to perform: choice_dup = tolower( choice_dup );  so the user can use 'N' and 'Y' along with 'n' and 'y'

Answer (score 3):

The loop will run forever because `while (choice_dup != 'y' || choice_dup != 'n')` will always evaluate to `true`.

You probably wanted: `while (choice_dup != 'y' && choice_dup != 'n')`

Comment: Yea now that you mentioned it thats a pretty stupid mistake. Thanks   again so much! :D

Comment: I have another problem now xD. For some reason when i run it even if i press y or n it doesnt work. But when i press 'y' it works but  again not properly. When i press 'y' or 'n' it runs again the printf order and then the proggram ends. Why? Can someone explain it to me? Also when i type more chars tha only one (exp. When i type: ysh it will run the printf coomand 3 times) it does this.

Comment: Well, the first thing that needs addressing is the fact that getChar(), which I assume reads in one character from stdin, is called twice in the loop. But in order to get a definitive answer as to what is happening, I guess you would need to post more code :-)

Answer (score 0):

should be this:

```
printf("\nDo you want to allow duplicate digits (y or n)?");
scanf(" %c", &choice_dup);
while (choice_dup != 'y' && choice_dup != 'n')
{
    printf("\nInvalid entry. Please choose y for yes and n for no.\t");
    choice_dup = getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
 while (choice_dup != 'y' && choice_dup != 'n') instead
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last while loop,i.e the one for choice_dup,change it to:

```
while(!(choice_dup=='y'| choice_dup=='n'))
```